# Blazor Server EditForm Model Initialize Net 8

Tags: c#, blazor, .net-8.0

With a background a long time ago in Razor MVC 5 I'm playing around with Blazor after using Angular 12+ for the recent years.

I'm struggling with EditForm Submit - only a simple application but it isn't behaving as I expected and I'm wondering what OnInitialized is doing.

The `CreateUserDto` I generated through NSwag and all of the fields have the required attribute.

The form that is being edited only contains four of the six properties, so they are not getting bound to within the `EditForm`.

Instead, as I don't want the user to have control over these, I initialised the properties in the `OnInitialize()` override method.

However when I populate the fields within the form and submit, I get errors saying that Username and Role are required.

If I remove `OnValidSubmit` and just use `Submit`, I can see that there properties are null, but I am unsure why.

Any help would be great, thanks.

Code is below:

```
@page "/users/register"
@inject IClient HttpClient
@inject NavigationManager _navManager;

<h3>Register New User</h3>
@if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
{
    <div class="alert-danger">
        <p>@message</p>
    </div>
}

<div class="card-body">
    <EditForm EditContext="_editContext" OnValidSubmit="HandleRegistration" FormName="Register">
        @* Enforces validation *@
        <DataAnnotationsValidator></DataAnnotationsValidator>
        @* Prints out anything thats invalid *@
        <ValidationSummary></ValidationSummary>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Email Address</label>
            <InputText class="form-control" @bind-Value="_registrationModel!.Email"></InputText>
            <ValidationMessage For="() => _registrationModel.Email"></ValidationMessage>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>First Name</label>
            <InputText class="form-control" @bind-Value="_registrationModel!.FirstName"></InputText>
            <ValidationMessage For="() => _registrationModel.FirstName"></ValidationMessage>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Last Name</label>
            <InputText class="form-control" @bind-Value="_registrationModel!.LastName"></InputText>
            <ValidationMessage For="() => _registrationModel.LastName"></ValidationMessage>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Password</label>
            <InputText class="form-control" @bind-Value="_registrationModel!.Password"></InputText>
            <ValidationMessage For="() => _registrationModel.Password"></ValidationMessage>
        </div>
        
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" >Register</button>
    </EditForm>
</div>


@code {

    private EditContext? _editContext;
    [SupplyParameterFromForm]
    public CreateUserDto? _registrationModel { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        _registrationModel ??= new CreateUserDto
        {
            Username = string.Empty,
            Role = "User"
        };
        _editContext = new EditContext(_registrationModel);
    }
    
    string message = String.Empty;
    
    private async Task HandleRegistration()
    {
        if (_registrationModel != null)
        {
            _registrationModel.Username = _registrationModel.Email;
            _registrationModel.Role = "User";
        }

        try
        {
            await HttpClient.RegisterAsync(_registrationModel);
            _navManager.NavigateTo("'/users/login");
        }
        catch (ApiException ae)
        {
            message = ae.Message;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            message = e.Message;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What render mode is you page running in?  I see no mode set on the page.  What is `Routes` set to in `App.razor`.

Comment: Wasn't aware I needed to set one?

<Router AppAssembly="typeof(Program).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <RouteView RouteData="routeData" DefaultLayout="typeof(Layout.MainLayout)"/>
        <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="routeData" Selector="h1"/>
    </Found>
</Router>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have `[SupplyParameterFromForm]` I'm assuming this is a statically rendered page.

The key point to understand is that this page exists in two contexts.  The model is built in `OnInitializedAsync` in the Http Request context.  The page is then returned to the browser as a static form.  You interact with it in a static browser context.

When you submit the form it builds a `CreateUserDto` from the form and posts it back to the server as the form data.  Any data not in the form is not submitted.  The Http Request context that handles the posted form does the validation and calls the correct valid/not valid hanlder.

Here's my MRE working version of your form where there's validation on the fields the user doesn't complete.  They are hidden fields within the form.  Note `string.Empty` satifies `[Required]`

```cs
@page "/"
@using System.ComponentModel;
@using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

<EditForm EditContext="_editContext" OnValidSubmit="HandleRegistration" OnInvalidSubmit="HandleValidation" FormName="Home">
    @* Enforces validation *@
    <DataAnnotationsValidator></DataAnnotationsValidator>
    @* Prints out anything thats invalid *@
    <ValidationSummary></ValidationSummary>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Email Address</label>
        <InputText class="form-control" @bind-Value="_registrationModel!.Email"></InputText>
        <ValidationMessage For="() => _registrationModel.Email"></ValidationMessage>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>First Name</label>
        <InputText class="form-control" @bind-Value="_registrationModel!.FirstName"></InputText>
        <ValidationMessage For="() => _registrationModel.FirstName"></ValidationMessage>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Last Name</label>
        <InputText class="form-control" @bind-Value="_registrationModel!.LastName"></InputText>
        <ValidationMessage For="() => _registrationModel.LastName"></ValidationMessage>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Password</label>
        <InputText class="form-control" @bind-Value="_registrationModel!.Password"></InputText>
        <ValidationMessage For="() => _registrationModel.Password"></ValidationMessage>
    </div>

    <InputText hidden @bind-Value="_registrationModel!.Username"></InputText>
    <InputText hidden @bind-Value="_registrationModel!.Role"></InputText>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Register</button>
</EditForm>

<div class="bg-dark text-white m-2 p-2">
    <pre>First Name: @_registrationModel!.FirstName</pre>
    <pre>Last Name: @_registrationModel.LastName</pre>
    <pre>Password: @_registrationModel.Password</pre>
    <pre>Role: @_registrationModel.Role</pre>
    <pre>Email: @_registrationModel.Email</pre>
    <pre>Username: @_registrationModel.Username</pre>

</div>

@code {
    private EditContext? _editContext;

    [SupplyParameterFromForm] public CreateUserDto? _registrationModel { get; set; }

    protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        _registrationModel ??= new CreateUserDto
            {
                Username = string.Empty,
                Role = "User"
            };

        _editContext = new EditContext(_registrationModel);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private async Task HandleValidation()
    {
        await Task.Yield();
    }

    private async Task HandleRegistration()
    {
        if (_registrationModel != null)
        {
            _registrationModel.Username = _registrationModel.Email;
            _registrationModel.Role = "User";
        }

        await Task.Yield();
    }

    public class CreateUserDto
    {
        [Required] public string? FirstName { get; set; }
        [Required] public string? LastName { get; set; }
        [Required] public string? Email { get; set; }
        [Required] public string? Password { get; set; }
        [Required] public string? Username { get; set; }
        [Required] public string? Role { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can remove the validation from the fields you set in the form handler.

```cs
@page "/"
@using System.ComponentModel;
@using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

<EditForm EditContext="_editContext" OnValidSubmit="HandleRegistration" OnInvalidSubmit="HandleValidation" FormName="Home">
    @* Enforces validation *@
    <DataAnnotationsValidator></DataAnnotationsValidator>
    @* Prints out anything thats invalid *@
    <ValidationSummary></ValidationSummary>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Email Address</label>
        <InputText class="form-control" @bind-Value="_registrationModel!.Email"></InputText>
        <ValidationMessage For="() => _registrationModel.Email"></ValidationMessage>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>First Name</label>
        <InputText class="form-control" @bind-Value="_registrationModel!.FirstName"></InputText>
        <ValidationMessage For="() => _registrationModel.FirstName"></ValidationMessage>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Last Name</label>
        <InputText class="form-control" @bind-Value="_registrationModel!.LastName"></InputText>
        <ValidationMessage For="() => _registrationModel.LastName"></ValidationMessage>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Password</label>
        <InputText class="form-control" @bind-Value="_registrationModel!.Password"></InputText>
        <ValidationMessage For="() => _registrationModel.Password"></ValidationMessage>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Register</button>
</EditForm>

<div class="bg-dark text-white m-2 p-2">
    <pre>First Name: @_registrationModel!.FirstName</pre>
    <pre>Last Name: @_registrationModel.LastName</pre>
    <pre>Password: @_registrationModel.Password</pre>
    <pre>Role: @_registrationModel.Role</pre>
    <pre>Email: @_registrationModel.Email</pre>
    <pre>Username: @_registrationModel.Username</pre>

</div>

@code {
    private EditContext? _editContext;

    [SupplyParameterFromForm] public CreateUserDto? _registrationModel { get; set; }

    protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        _registrationModel ??= new CreateUserDto
            {
                Username = string.Empty,
                Role = "User"
            };

        _editContext = new EditContext(_registrationModel);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private async Task HandleValidation()
    {
        await Task.Yield();
    }

    private async Task HandleRegistration()
    {
        if (_registrationModel != null)
        {
            _registrationModel.Username = _registrationModel.Email;
            _registrationModel.Role = "User";
        }

        await Task.Yield();
    }

    public class CreateUserDto
    {
        [Required] public string? FirstName { get; set; }
        [Required] public string? LastName { get; set; }
        [Required] public string? Email { get; set; }
        [Required] public string? Password { get; set; }
        public string? Username { get; set; }
        public string? Role { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the explaination, I'm still getting required errors, so I think something else could be at play. If I go with option 2, and remove the [Required] then it works, but the API models shouldn't be touched as they are required.

You mentioned that their are two contexts, one on initialise and the other is created when the form is submitted, as the properties are assigned to initialise, is it only the properties that are parsed and not the model with the pre set properties. Is it better to use a dynamically rendered page, would that get rid of the issue I'm seeing here?

Comment: "Is it better to use a dynamically rendered page, would that get rid of the issue I'm seeing here?"  Yes, and the form will be more interactive on validation.

Comment: Ah okay. IIs it through EditForm or should that be ignored in favour of HTML? Do you have a link to an example of what this looks like?

Comment: Not sure how you Solution is configured, but you should just be able to add `@RenderMode InteractiveServer` to the above pages.

Comment: Yeah, that sorted it, adding `@rendermode RenderMode.InteractiveServer` into the model fixed it, thank you!